# How to exclude a module from symbol parsing of lldb?

Tags: lldb, debug-symbols

Are there any lldb settings via I can exclude a loaded module from the initial lldb symbol parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

You can create your target with `target create -dtrue` and lldb won't search for any dependent libraries.  But when you `run` and libraries start loading, lldb will do the initial parse as libraries load.

You can set the setting `target.preload-symbols` to `false` and lldb will try to only look for symbol information "when it needs it".  This isn't limited to a specific library, but if you are careful to specify the target shared libraries for your breakpoints you can reduce the "whole world" searches that cause lldb to have to read in symbols.

If the problem is that some libraries take too long to parse, you might try the new `symbols.enable-lldb-index-cache` setting, which caches the results of the symbol parsing for use in future lldb sessions.

Comment: My actual issue is that lldb is crashing during the parsing of a given module (that I do not have control over) The actual workaround I'm started to use meanwhile was to build an lldb version that skips that given module by name. I will give a shot to target.preload-symbols. Probably it would be worth a try to add a feature request to lldb? Thank you so much for the detailed answer!

Comment: Certainly file a bug about lldb crashing during the parsing of a module.  If you can provide the module that lldb is crashing on, that would be great.  Then just file a report with the llvm project issues tracker: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.  Even if you can't provide the library, we can probably give you some logs to turn on that will help us debug the problem.

Comment: Doing "don't parse symbols for module X" is tricky because what if you step into code in module X, or crash there, then you have to be prepared to operate in this weird environment.  So we have resisted doing that and tried instead to make lldb's parsing lazy enough that it doesn't cost a lot to parse the modules.  Certainly we would prefer to fix the bug that causes lldb to crash parsing the module than add support for "don't parse these modules"...

Comment: The only reason I did not file a bug report yet and thought about a "don't parse these modules" feature option instead is that my machine is not a regular one therefore I'm almost sure this crash with the "same" module will not happen in most of the cases and I think this is not really an lldb bug (though I agree, maybe it would be much better/cleaner if lldb could prepare to such strange exceptions as well) I do not want to trash here more on this if you wish I could send you all the available details privately.